# Increment by one when pressing a button (in Ajax call)

Tags: php, button, increment

I have some markup `<span class="points-count">0</span>`. When pressing a button I would like to increment this value by one in php. How do I achieve this?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/marcuswhybrow/zRX2D/2/

Answer (score 0):

> You can done this using **jQuery** ,**javascript** etc., if you want only in **PHP** then check this code

```
    <?php  

$current_value = 0;
if($_POST['count']){
    $current_value = $_POST['count'];
    $current_value++;} 
?>
<form action="" method="POST">
    <span class="points-count"><?=$current_value?></span>
    <input type="hidden" name="count" value="<?=$current_value?>">
    <button type="submit">Add</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to make a counting number using ajax call here is the sample:

counter.php:

```
<?php
    $counter = $_GET['current_value'] + 1;       //value is increase here
    echo json_encode(['new_value' => $counter]); //return the value in JSON format
?>
```

Your HTML File:

```
<span class="points-count">0</span>
<button onclick="count()">Increase</button>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function count() {
        $.ajax({
            url     : "counter.php",
            type    : "GET",
            dataType: "json",
            data    : {
                current_value: $(".points-count").html() //set value here
            },
            success: function(data) {
                $(".points-count").html(data.new_value); //finally, get the returned value of the php script
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

Instead of using php. 
you can use jquery or javascript for this. php is for server side render only.